# Library to identify the MIME Type of InDesign files in Python

Tags: python, mime-types, adobe-indesign, ipython-magic

Anybody knows a library that helps to identify InDesign files?

I was trying `python-magic`, but i got `application/octet-stream` for `.indd` files and `application/zip` for `.idml` files (I know this is a zip file indeed).

I'm aware there is no official MIME type for InDesign (it does not appear in the IANA's listing: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html) but, it could be great if somebody knows a library that gives `application/x-indesign` or `application/vnd.adobe.indesign-idml-package` or whatever for these kind of files. I need a library, not an external/online service. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

FWIW, Adobe provides a library for investigating XMP metadata where you will find information about the application that generated the file. I am not sure how it can help but just in case: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html